# Transfer data-id to multiple modals

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have this table:

```
       <table class="table">
    <tr>
    <td class="detail">
       <a class="btn btn-default btn-xs" href="" data-email="<?php echo $us->email; ?>">Email</a>
<a class="btn btn-default btn-xs" href="" data-id="<?php echo $us->id; ?>">Profile</a>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

And I get data-email value with this javascript:

```
<script>
$('.table .detail a').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var email = $(this).data('email');

  $.ajax({
    url: 'admin/send_email.php?token=<?php echo $token; ?>',
    data: {email: email},
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'HTML'
  }).done(function(resp) {
    $('#modalContent .modal-body').html(resp)
  $('#modalContent').modal('show');
  });
});
</script>
```

How I can get data-id in another modal? I have tried adding class id in `class="btn btn-default btn-xs"` but don't work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're currently getting the value of `data-email` when the email link is clicked.  If you also want to get the `data-id` from the next DOM link element, you can do:

```
var id = $(this).next('a').data('id');
```

You can then pass `id` to your AJAX call (or do whatever it is that needs to be done with the profile id).

If you're asking how to get the `data-id` when the Profile link is clicked, you can do:

```
$('.table .detail a').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var email = $(this).data('email');
  var id = $(this).data('id');
  if (email !== undefined) {
    //email link was clicked
  } else if (id !== undefined) {
    //profile link was clicked
  }
  //do other stuff
});
```